# Why Clone is used in Custom Authentication and login Modules?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

The clone method of the authenticator creates a deep copy of the object members.

```
public WorkLightAuthenticator clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        MyCustomAuthenticator otherAuthenticator = (MyCustomAuthenticator) super.clone();
        otherAuthenticator.authenticationData = new HashMap<String, Object>(authenticationData);
        return otherAuthenticator;
    }
```

1. Why we need a copy of the object member ?
2. If created a copy where the copy is being used ?
3. Any scenario for the use of the clone and where it is being stored ?
4. What are all the data copied in "**authenticationData**" ?

Answer (score 0):

This method was used in older versions of Worklight and is still there for backwards compatibility reasons. You may opt to not use it and throw clone not supported exception.

At the time, it was used for scenarios such as Device SSO where cloning was done for the authentication context in order to pass objects via memory from session to session.

This is no longer done this way these days (starting Worklight 6.1 or so). Today this action is done via the Worklight database.

The authenticationData contains data that is propogated from the authenticator to the login module; per-realm.

Let me know if the above helps.